# Cheat-Proof techniques for Online Game(TCP)

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm creating a game and i'm really worried about hacking, so i'm writting a anti-cheat inside the game, i searched how the hacks now-a-days are written and i found some patterns, first of all, almost every hack uses a thread(Usually with CreateThread()) to create the checking loop(check if hack is on/off), do any of you have a good way to check if the thread is not from the game?PS:I also use threads from outside the code(inside DLLs)

Comment: What is going to prevent them from patching your "check for foreign code" code?

Comment: The best way to prevent cheating in a multiplayer game is to do all of the important stuff on the server that the players do not have access to.

Comment: @Retired There are operations that must run on the client. While having the server manage the sensitive data is a good strategy, it cannot guard against client-bound attacks, like aim-bot software.

Comment: @IInspectable It depends on the game.  As an example, in a rts/moba game not sending data about anything covered by fog of war, or perception bubbles in mmo games.  You can never eliminate every possibility of cheating, but you can use analytics to flag outliers as well for additional observation.  One thing is sure, and that is you can never trust the client to be secure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is almost certainly better to find a different way to "anticheat", since as cdhowie points out, there's nothing to prevent someone clever from splatting over your anticheat code with something that doesn't do what you want.

There are some techniques that work much better:

Let the server do all the "important" stuff, such as figuring out what score you get and how many lives you have left, and if the player becomes a zoombie (tries to move after he's dead), something is wrong.

Another method that I think works reasonably well is to basically record a "log" of how the player got to where they are - how many lives they used, how many enemies killed, what type of enemy, score of each enemy, weapon used, shots fired, how long it took to do all that, and then let a server verify that it's "reasonable" - so if someone ups the number of lives they have, or changes the weapon to create 100x the damage, or slows down the enemies or speeds up the players time, it will show up in the "log", and the log can then be discarded as "fake".